# Selecting the correct element to trigger form submit from within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-selectors, form-submit

I have several forms on a page.  The forms are actually PayPal "add to cart" buttons.  When a user clicks on a button, an alert box asks for their zip code.  If the zip code in in the array of okZips, I want to programmatically follow the link through the submit button to the cart, but I just can't quite get the correct element to attach .submit() to.

```
$(this).add("div.check-zip").add("form:first").submit();//this submits the first form on the page
$(this).add("div.check-zip").add("form").submit();//this submits the last form on the page
$(event.target).add("form").submit();//this doesn't submit anything
$(myEvent).add("form").submit();//this submits the last form where myEvent is a global variable
```

The pen can be found here: 
http://codepen.io/enielsen0001/pen/KwEbzz

How do I select the correct element to apply the .submit()?  Am I going about this all the wrong way?

Comment: `.submit()` is a method of `form` elements. It is POJS, not jQuery.

Comment: @roxxypoxxy  Thank you so much.  I am a newbie at JS/JQuery and I was getting very frustrated.  You really helped to clarify how to use the _event_ .  Is it just ugly to mix JS and JQuery, or is there another reason?

Comment: Jquery is a JavaScript library itself designed to help users to access DOM. So, when you include jquery you should use Jquery methods. Well you can do the things in plain javascript the things you do using jquery, but then it doesn't make any sense to include jquery. A good programming practice is to follow a convention and be consistence. Either you use plain js or jquery to access DOM but not mix them haphazardly.BTW you should have put that comment in my answer, as it was reply to my answer, not in your question itself.

Comment: And do accept answer as correct if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not going all the wrong way but it is definitely the baddest and dirtiest way. It seems like you don't know what you are doing. Your classes are messed up, you are mixing jQuery and plain js, you are using while and for. It seems like you have deliberately copy pasted code with no idea what it is. Please have atleast beginner's js/jQuery knowledge before posting questions.

However, here is the updated pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPJJwJ.

You would need the actual form object for submit to work.

```
// myEvent is event itself not element
$(myEvent.target).parent("form").submit();
```

I have refactored stuffs involving while and for loops you used. Compare your code with updated code. Hope it helps: